# Stack of process 0 in Linux kernel 0.11

Tags: c, linux, assembly, linux-kernel, x86

I'm currently learning linux kernel source code (v0.11). The following is the `main()` function of `init/main.c`:

```
void main(void) 
{
    ...
    move_to_user_mode();
    if (!fork()) {      /* we count on this going ok */
        init();
    }
```

where in `move_to_user_mode`, process 0 goes to user mode by doing this:

```
#define move_to_user_mode() \
__asm__ ("movl %%esp,%%eax\n\t" \
    "pushl $0x17\n\t" \
    "pushl %%eax\n\t" \
    "pushfl\n\t" \
    "pushl $0x0f\n\t" \
    "pushl $1f\n\t" \
    "iret\n" \
    "1:\tmovl $0x17,%%eax\n\t" \
    "movw %%ax,%%ds\n\t" \
    "movw %%ax,%%es\n\t" \
    "movw %%ax,%%fs\n\t" \
    "movw %%ax,%%gs" \
    :::"ax")
```

After `iret`, it seems like that the user mode `ss:esp` points to the same stack as it is in kernel mode. i.e. p0's user stack = p0's kernel stack. Is this true?

When p0 calls `fork`, it calls `copy_process`, which copies its user mode `ss:esp` to p1's `tss->ss` and `tss->esp`. So will p1 share the same user mode stack as p0? If so, p1's user stack = p0's user stack = p0's kernel stack. Will this cause any problem?

The `copy_process` is as following:

```
int copy_process(int nr,long ebp,long edi,long esi,long gs,long none,
        long ebx,long ecx,long edx,
        long fs,long es,long ds,
        long eip,long cs,long eflags,long esp,long ss)
{
    ...
    p->tss.esp = esp;
    ...
    p->tss.ss = ss & 0xffff;
    ...
}
```

P.S. p0's kernel stack is below LOW_MEMORY, which means it does not support COW.

Comment: *`ss:esp` points to the same stack as it is in kernel mode* The same virtual address, yes.  And since nothing changes CR3 to a different set of page tables, yes, that's the same stack memory. `iret` will trigger TSS task-switch stuff, although that *doesn't* change CR3 for you.  So I think this is basically dropping from kernel to user mode for this task, like the macro name indicates.  Presumably with memory mapped so user-space can access it.

Comment: Thanks @Peter. But if the user mode stack shares the same memory with the kernel mode stack, this may cause conflict to memory usage. Say if the process is in user mode and has something useful in its stack (e.g. it is in a function's stack frame), then it uses `int 80` to trap to kernel mode, which pushes `ss`, `esp`, `eflags`, `cs` and `eip` to the kernel stack. If user mode stack = kernel mode stack, the values pushed by `int 80` will overlap the values pushed in user mode.

Comment: Possibly.  But does task `0` *do* anything in user-space?

Comment: It calls `fork()` to generate p1, and then calls `pause()` in an infinite loop. This two system calls are inline functions which do not use user stack. So this may not be a problem for p0. But after `fork()`, it seems that p1's user stack = p0's user stack = p0's kernel stack. I know this is for COW, but p0's stack is in the data segment of the kernel and it is below LOW_MEMORY, which does not support COW. And p1 do have a lot of work to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

p0's user stack is the `user_stack` defined in `kernel/sched.c`, which is the same stack used before `move_to_user_mode`, and which is the value of the pushed `esp` in `move_to_user_mode`. And after `move_to_user_mode`, p0 should not use this space (this is why the following `fork` and `pause` are inline function) since p1's user stack also points to this space when p0 calls `fork` to produce p1. This space is set to read-only in p1's page table. When p1 wants to use this space, it will trigger a page fault, and then trigger COW for this space, i.e. the kernel will allocate a new page for p1's stack.

Conclusion:

1. p0's user stack = p1's user stack right after `fork`.
2. p0 does not use its user stack.
3. p1 will trigger COW on this stack space when it wants to write to the stack.